# Cognos: How to customize the values shown in column Gaph

Tags: charts, cognos

I have a column chart stacked. I want to show both actual value as well as the percentage value on top of each stack. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

To display the value or the percentage, select the Bar chart Icon next to the Series Item, in

```
properties->Chart Labels->Values select 'Show'.
```

Where they are displayed is determiend by Value Location.  If you have selected the Stacked grouping type, you will see values. If you selected the Stacked 100% type you will see percentages.

You cannot display both values and percentages in the same Series item in Cognos 8.4 (Doubt you can do it in Cognos 10 either).

Comment: I discovered recently an alternative.  While you can only display one number above the bar, you can customize the hover over text to display additional items, so long as those items appear in your chart.  Change 'Custom Label' to 'Show', then select type 'Report Calculation'.  This will change the name of the item being displayed in hover over.  here you can add additional items, with '= ' and their value, and carriage returns, making for a nice comprehensive list of values on the hover over.